# Microsoft Storage Spaces without ReFS

Tags: storage-spaces, refs

I'm testing a new build of a surveillance, video recording server. My OS (Windows 10 Professional) is on an SSD and my data is stored to 8 spinning disks. I wanted to try out Storage Spaces and noticed that ReFS is not an option with Windows Professional any more. Is it "safe" to use Storage Spaces with NTFS or would it be worth it to go with Windows 10 Pro for Workstations to get the ReFS option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a clear answer here, as it depends on your requirements. Can you lose the data? How long can your PVR "server" be down while you repair NTFS offline?

ReFS has integrations with Storage Spaces, so that it can recover files from mirror/parity blocks, thus making repairs extremely fast *and* online, without any interruption.

If you want to use ReFS (and I think you should), then your options are:

- Windows Server - since you're saying "video recording server"
- Windows 10 Enterprise
- Windows 10 Pro for Workstations

Comment: Note: I'm presuming that you have read the ReFS docs to make sure that your application is covered by the ReFS feature table - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/refs/refs-overview

Comment: Server OS is not necessary. I'm mainly looking for a less expensive alternative to RAID hardware but still be somewhat reliable. Sounds like the Workstation edition with ReFS is worth a try.